# Fulltext-Search plugin for Vuepress static site generator?

Tags: text-search, plug-in, static-site-generator

These days I am writing technical documentation with Markdown, using the [Vuepress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) static site generator.

The default theme has a search box built in, but this search box only indexes the Headlines and what appears in the sidebar. I need a fulltext search mechanism. Is there a plugin or an external too that can give me fulltext search easily?

Update: I know they mention [AlgoliaSearch in the Vuepress documentation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#algolia-docsearch), but I want my own until my writing project is finished.

Comment: Might be worth looking at the following article which explains how to implement it using FlexSearch: https://ahmadmostafa.com/2019/12/09/build-better-search-in-vuepress-site/

Comment: Meanwhile I've changed my mind, and have resorted to Algolia, it's just 20-30 pages I'm talking about,